# Mocking with PyTest: Improving my XML write/parse unit test

Tags: xml, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

So I am rather new with `pytest` and `mock`, but still have experience with `junit` and mocking with `mockito` for `groovy` (which comes with an handy `when(...).thenAnswer/Return` function)

I wrote a simple class to parse and write xml files. This class sole purpose for existence is to be mocked in order to unit test the plugin I am currently working on. This personal project is also used as a learning tool to help me in my work duties (devOps python based)

Obviously, I needed to test it too.

Here is the class:

```
from lxml import etree

from organizer.tools.exception_tools import ExceptionPrinter


class XmlFilesOperations(object):

    @staticmethod
    def write(document_to_write, target):
        document_to_write.write(target, pretty_print=True)

    @staticmethod
    def parse(file_to_parse):
        parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

        try:
            return etree.parse(file_to_parse, parser)
        except Exception as something_happened:
            ExceptionPrinter.print_exception(something_happened)
```

And here is the unit test for it:

```
import mock

from organizer.tools.xml_files_operations import XmlFilesOperations

FILE_NAME = "toto.xml"

@mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree.ElementTree')
def test_write(mock_document):

    XmlFilesOperations.write(mock_document, FILE_NAME)
    mock_document.write.assert_called_with(FILE_NAME, pretty_print=True)

@mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree')
def test_parse(mock_xml):

    XmlFilesOperations.parse(FILE_NAME)
    mock_xml.parse.assert_called()
```

Also, here is the pipfile used for this python environment:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
lxml = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-lazy-fixture = "*"
mock = "*"
MKLpy = "*"
```

I would like to improve this test by making use of the `assert_called_with` function in the `test_parse` function. However to make it work I need to get the exact parser that is used in the `XmlFilesOperations.parse` method so I imagined mocking it too. For this I need the `etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)` call to return a mocked object

Here is what I tried:

```
import mock
import pytest
from lxml import etree

from organizer.tools.xml_files_operations import XmlFilesOperations

FILE_NAME = "toto.xml"

@pytest.fixture()
def mock_parser():
    parser = mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree.XMLParser').start()
    with mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree.XMLParser', return_value=parser):
        yield parser

    parser.stop()

@mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree')
def test_parse(mock_xml, mock_parser):

    XmlFilesOperations.parse(FILE_NAME)
    mock_xml.parse.assert_called_with(FILE_NAME, mock_parser)
```

I obtain the following error:

```
    def raise_from(value, from_value):
>       raise value
E       AssertionError: expected call not found.
E       Expected: parse('toto.xml', <MagicMock name='XMLParser' id='65803280'>)
E       Actual: parse('toto.xml', <MagicMock name='etree.XMLParser()' id='66022384'>)
```

So the mocked object returned by the call is not the same mocked object that I created.

With Mockito, I would have done something like this:

```
parser = etree.XmlParser()
when(etree.XMLParser(any()).thenReturn(parser)
```

And it would work.
How could I fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your approach is the sequence of mocking the objects. The fixture is called first, and while mocking the parser, it does not use the mocked `etree`, but the real one, while in the test the parser is used from the mocked `etree`, which is another mock created by that mock.
Additionally, you did check for the parser *method* instead of the parser itself.

Here is what should work without using a fixture:

```python
@mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree.XMLParser')
@mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree')
def test_parse(mock_xml, mock_parser):
    XmlFilesOperations.parse(FILE_NAME)
    mock_xml.parse.assert_called_with(FILE_NAME, mock_parser())
```

Another possibility is to exchange the fixture and the patch, so that they are used in the correct order:

```python
@pytest.fixture()
def mock_etree():
    with mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree') as mocked_etree:
        yield mocked_etree


@mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree.XMLParser')
def test_parse(mock_xml_parser, mock_etree):
    XmlFilesOperations.parse(FILE_NAME)
    mock_etree.parse.assert_called_with(FILE_NAME, mock_xml_parser())
```

Finally, if you want to use only fixtures, you can make them dependent on each other:

```python
@pytest.fixture()
def mock_etree():
    with mock.patch('organizer.tools.xml_files_operations.etree') as mocked_etree:
        yield mocked_etree


@pytest.fixture()
def mock_parser(mock_etree):
    parser = mock.Mock()
    with mock.patch.object(mock_etree, 'XMLParser', parser):
        yield parser


def test_parse(mock_parser, mock_etree):
    XmlFilesOperations.parse(FILE_NAME)
    mock_etree.parse.assert_called_with(FILE_NAME, mock_parser())
```

Comment: Well it worked thank you, however I am still unsure I understand why !

Comment: The answer was admittedly not clear enough, as it did not show the main problem. I edited it to be hopefully clearer now.

Comment: Thanks ! I actually came to something very similar in another test, where mocking in a fixture was mandatory.