# Pytest: Use a mock in a fixture?

Tags: mocking, pytest, fixtures

This question is a follow up on my previous question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037140/mocking-with-pytest-improving-my-xml-write-parse-unit-test/61039742#61039742)

I would like to define a fixture that will run a function for each of it's parameters, before returning it to me.

However, the function cannot run without another validation function being mocked, because the validation cannot be performed without a file system.

Here is what it looks like currently:

```
mocked_validation = mock.Mock() mocked_validation.return_value = True

@pytest.fixture(params = GAMELIST_ROOT_VALUES) def basic_parser(request):
    return GameListParser(request.param)

@pytest.fixture @mock.patch('organizer.parser.game_list_parser.GameListParser.validate', mocked_validation) def ready_parser(basic_parser):
    basic_parser.parse()
    return basic_parser
```

However the fixture will fail at the basic_parser.parser() call, during the validation.

I use this mock for tests, it works well, so it must have to do with the fact that it's in a fixture.

Is there anyway to do that ? I do not wish to repeat this line of code for every test

This can be tested with the following class:

```
class GameListParser(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def parse(self):
        if not self.validate():
            raise Exception("Parsing fail")

    def validate(self):
        return False
```

Edit: Adding another try, but still failing:

```
@pytest.fixture
def ready_parser(basic_parser):
    with mock.patch('organizer.parser.game_list_parser.GameListParser.validate') as validation:
        validation.return_value = True
        basic_parser.parse()
        return basic_parser
```

Answer (score 2):

Found solution with yield:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def ready_parser(basic_parser):
    with mock.patch('organizer.parser.game_list_parser.GameListParser.validate') as validation:
            validation.return_value = True
            basic_parser.parse()
            yield basic_parser
```

But I feel sad I cannot reuse the definition I already have for mocked_validation, I tried again as a decorator and it's not working